# Yii url rule with regular expression

Tags: regex, yii, rules

I have a rule:

```
'employee/renewOffer/<id_offer:\d+>;<title:.+>' => 'company/renewOffer',
```

http://www.example.com/123;title-of-post

which concerns to any **SINGLE** offer and this works great, but how this rule should be look if if select **MULTIPLE** offers. Link will look like this (comma separated ID's):

http://www.example.com/123,456,12,5;title-of-post

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, but I'm guessing it can be achieved by changing `\d+` to `[\d,]+`.

Comment: I'd say @ndn is probably right.  Or, to be even more permissive, `[^;]+` or even just `.+?`.

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry that I was not too specific.  I try explain what I mean - I have first URL (http://www.example.com/123;title-of-post) and rule like I wrote and this works fine. But instead of one ID, I must enter many ID's (second URL). With the same rule I get 404 error because of commas I think. Hope I'm right now more clear

Comment: Did you try what @ndn has suggested yet?  I'm not at all familiar with Yii and it's rules, but based on the example, I would think that would work.

Comment: Huh, I'll try earlier but without brackets [] and get error, now I try again and this is correct! Thank you so much

Comment: You are using comma and semi-colon in the path , that's daring man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by ndn, you can allow for commas by replacing the `\d+` in your rule with `[\d,]+`.  In other words, change the rule to this:

```
'employee/renewOffer/<id_offer:[\d,]+>;<title:.+>' => 'company/renewOffer',
```

The square brackets create a character class (any of the characters listed inside the brackets are allowed).  So, by putting `\d` and `,` in the character class, that allows for any digit or any comma to match.  However, that solution only specifically allows for digits and commas.  If you want it to be more flexible, you could change it to accept any character by using `.`.  For instance:

```
'employee/renewOffer/<id_offer:.+?>;<title:.+>' => 'company/renewOffer',
```

The `?` after the `.+` just makes the `+` non-greedy.  That means it will capture as little as it can rather than as much as it can.

Comment: Thank you and thank for ndt for help for great feedback